# CSRF attack detected when submitting data using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony1, csrf

I'm trying to submit a form using jquery in symfony 1.4, but CSRF attack detected error pops up each time. This is the code i use to submit the form data:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      cache: false,
      url: $('#assign-form form').attr('action'),
      data: (
        'activity[id]=' + $('#activity_id').val() +
        '&activity[_csrf_token]=' + $('#activity__csrf_token').val() +
        '&activity[assigned_to_user_id]=' + $('#activity_assigned_to_user_id').val() +
        '&activity[assigned_to_group_id]=' + $('#activity_assigned_to_group_id').val()
      )
});
```

Am i missing something?

Thanks,
Radu.

Comment: Could paste the HTML code of your form and maybe the PHP that is supposed to handle the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to look at is whether the Form object that is validating the input is the exact same class as the the one that generated the token.  By default, the class is used in the generation of the CSRF token.

If, for example, you had an instance of a subclass of a form used to generate the form html and then you posted to an action that used the ancestor form class, the validation would most likely fail by default.

It's possible to override the token creation if it turns out this is your issue.

Also, have you verified that the value of the token field actually includes a token? A console.log() may help you discover this.

Um...as I look closer at your code, another thing to look at is that you're building a query string to pass in 'data'.  Have you tried passing an actual JSON-style object instead?

Comment: The form class is the same. 
Never worked with JSON-style objects before... any articles i should read to get started?

Comment: By JSON-style objects, I simply mean use a JavaScript object to store key/value pairs.  Ultimately $.ajax() will be converting this to a query string for you, but it can make things a bit more readable and easier to extend.

Here's a pastie of what the code above might look like when using a JSON-style object:

http://pastie.org/812536

Tons of articles regarding JSON out there, but I'm not sure of a definitive one to suggest.  To familiarize yourself with JSON concepts, however, the best place to start is http://json.org/

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Usual cause is that the browser is not accepting cookies - have you checked that the cookies are being returned as expected (e.g. iehttpheaders, wireshark, tamperdata)?

Did you configure the secret in settings.yml?

C.

Comment: The browser is accepting cookies.
Yes, the configuration in security.yml is:
csrf_secret: 42f41325ba2c6809722d2b164f954f74c1b82fdb

Answer (score 0):

This little issue has driven me mad in the past.

If it's acceptable to you to disable CSRF protection for this particular form (which it often can be), you can add the following to your Form class in /lib/form/... folder:

```
public function configure ()

  $this->disableLocalCSRFProtection();
```

I believe it's possible to disable CSRF for a particular instance of the form as well if you don't always wish to have it disabled, but I haven't tried this / don't have the code at hand.

Comment: You can use the following code in your action to disable the CSRF protection for a particular instance of the form:

    $form = new MyForm();
    $form->disableLocalCSRFProtection();

Answer (score 0):

Does the session cookie really received it with ajax query ? your session cookie as returned by server should be exactly the same with a plain HTTP request (for instance the first request initiating session management) and with XMLHttpRequest, otherwise you'll get trouble with CSRF.

Answer (score 0):

$('#activity__csrf_token').val()

Did you mean to have a double underscore in that element id?